# не удаётся запустить программу в Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 не удаётся найти указанный файл

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Создаю проект: File > New > Project... > Empty Project

Создаю файл: File > New > File.. > C++ File

Пишу стандартную программу "Hello, world!"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

Жму ctrl+f5. Идёт построение, ошибок в коде нет, но выскакивает ошибка "не удаётся запустить программу "путь до exe файла" Не удаётся найти указанный файл.

[image: Скриншот]

Самого exe файла по этому пути нет, он даже не создаётся.

Буду признателен за вашу помощь.

Comment: Возможно, что надо установить, какой файл является запускаемым.

Comment: Или переименуйте файл source1.cpp в test47.cpp

Comment: Как вариант попробуйте rebuild запустить

Comment: и меня сильно смущает, что вашего cpp файла не видно в solution explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо не просто создать файл, а создать и добавить в проект. Делается это так, в solution explorer нажимаете правой кнопкой по Source Files выбираете Add->New Item. Если у вас уже файл создан, как сейчас, то там же выбираете Add->Existing Item и выбираете ваш файл

Comment: Спасибо помог. Никак не мог понять что не так